# Rendering HTML symbols/entities in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, character-encoding, html-entities

is it just me, or does Chrome no longer render HTML characters such as the `&mdash;`? I've tried changing the DOCTYPE, changing the character encoding meta tag, changing the character encoding option in Chrome, and even using the entity number instead of the entity name. I cannot for the life of me get Chrome to display an em dash, and I've noticed that it isn't rendering it for other sites as well. Has anyone else had this problem also?

***UPDATE***

> Are you sure the font you're using
>   actually has an em dash character? - Andrew Marshall

It just dawned on me what's going on. A while ago, I wanted to be able to use Helvetica Neue on Windows, and I didn't want to fork out a few hundred bucks, so I copied the font file from a Mac, converted it to a TTF on Ubuntu, and brought it over to Windows. I guess the tool I used didn't convert all the characters because it obviously can't display the em dash. The only reason I noticed the problem in Chrome is because the other non-webkit browsers wouldn't use Helvetica Neue for some reason.

Arg... I feel stupid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you give an example of this happening? I cannot replicate this in Chrome 11.

Comment: I've -1'd this just for the lack of actual information. If you can't get a particular character to show, then a screenshot or link to a page that doesn't work would be infinitely more useful that just saying it doesn't work.

Comment: Here's the webpage: http://ve.k6krfxtk.vesrv.com/
Here's the screenshot: http://ve.k6krfxtk.vesrv.com/screen.jpg

Let me know if you see something differently.

Comment: Just to remove any doubt, that screenshot was taken in Chrome 11.0.696.60.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd argue that HTML entities should be avoided (except `&amp;`, of course). Instead just use the actual character and declare (and save) your HTML as UTF-8, something you should already be doing.

There are several top sites that do this, in particular with the use of `©` instead of `&copy;`.

Comment: I tried that also and using the actual character didn't work either. Plus, it broke validation. Thanks though!

Comment: It shouldn't break validation. Ensure you're declaring and saving as UTF-8. Are you sure the font you're using actually has an em dash character?

Comment: Also, I don't know what to tell you, but I'm seeing the em dash on you're site just fine here http://imgur.com/C4JCf (Mac 10.6.7, Chrome 11.0.696.57)

Comment: I didn't realize I just needed to declare my page as UTF-8. That's good to know. Thanks!

Comment: As a word of advice you should always declare all your HTML as UTF-8 unless you have a really really good reason to use another encoding.